# Какое минимальное 8-разрядное двоичное число вы можете представить, используя системы представления двоичных чисел, перечисленные ниже?

Tags: системы-счисления, информатика

Какое минимальное (наименьшее отрицательное?) 8-разрядное двоичное число вы можете представить, используя системы  представления двоичных чисел, перечисленные ниже?
*Двоичное число без знака,
*Дополнительный код,
*Прямой код.

Мое предположение:
Двоичное число без знака 0,
Дополнительный код -128,
Прямой код -127.

Но мне нужно знать точно, если не трудно с пояснением почему.
Считается ли в прямом коду знаковый разряд за за разряд,то есть нужно считать 7 разрядов + 1 минус?

Comment: *Мое предположение: Двоичное число без знака 0 ...* Если задание процитировано точно - неверно. Акцентирую: *Какое минимальное (наименьшее **отрицательное**?)*. Ноль не является отрицательным числом, для беззнаковых правильный ответ - никакое.

Answer (score 0):

> Мое предположение: Двоичное число без знака 0, Дополнительный код -128, Прямой код -127.

Верно.

> Считается ли в прямом коду знаковый разряд за за разряд,то есть нужно считать 7 разрядов + 1 минус?

Да.